# raise a form key up event from another class using c#?

Tags: c#

here is my form key up event

form2

```
     public void Form2_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        LogKeyEvent(e.KeyCode);
    }
    public void LogKeyEvent(Keys e)
    {
        //listBox1.Items.Add(e.KeyCode);
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\Prova.txt", true))
        {
            sw.Write(e);
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
```

class2

now i want to raise it from another class using c# that class code is this

```
   private void OnEventArrived(object sender, System.Management.EventArrivedEventArgs e2)
          {
                  if (activewindows == "Command Propmpt") {

                       LogKeyEvent(Key.L); //from another class

                   }
           }
```

f is form object but how to pass parameter to this event and raise it or actually i want KeyEventArgs  to be raised is their any other way actually i am making a key logger

> Error 1   The name 'Key' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raising a "form key up event" *smells*; what you *actually want* is to perform the routine which is executed on a "form key up event". So I suggest *extracting a method*:

Before:

```
  // Smells: 
  // 1. Ugly arguments: 
  //   sender (what is it? Can I ,say, pass 123 as a sender)
  //   e (why on Earth should I generate event args when all I want is to append a file?!)
  // 2. Wrong name: Form2_KeyUp (very bad name to writing file routine)
  public void Form2_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    listBox1.Items.Add(e.KeyCode);
    // wrap IDisposable into using
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\Prova.txt", true);
    sw.Write(e.KeyCode);
    sw.Close();
  }
```

After:

```
  //TODO: please, think over the right name
  public void AppendKeyCode(Keys keyCode) {
    listBox1.Items.Add(keyCode);

    File.AppendAllText(@"d:\Prova.txt", keyCode.ToString());
  }

  // Please, notice "private": do not expose such methods
  private void Form2_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    AppendKeyCode(e.KeyCode);
  }
```

To call `AppendKeyCode` from another form:

```
  if (ti == "Command Propmpt") {
    // If you have many Form2 opened, let's take the last one
    Form2 form = Application.OpenForms
      .OfType<Form2>()
      .LastOrDefault(); 

    if (form != null)
      form.AppendKeyCode(Keys.F1); //TODO: put right key code here
  }
```

Comment: actually i want to get keypress event may be for is runnig or not can you give me hint how to detect when user press any key using c#

Comment: now can you only tell me how to get the key press event like keylogger when ever user press key i add it into list box

Comment: @north start: well, let's *state the problem right*. You want monitoring *key up* (on some forms/all forms/trough out the operation system - select the right choice, please) and put key codes into `From2.listBox1.Items` and append the file. Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you separate this logging with another `public` method, and use this as an instance method called from events in both the classes?

```
public void LogKeyEvent(Keys  e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(e);
    using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\Prova.txt", true))
    {
         sw.Write(e);
         sw.Close();
    }
}
```

Now this method can be invoked from both the classes with instance reference.

```
public void Form2_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     LogKeyEvent(e.KeyCode);
}
```

and from other class

```
if (ti == "Command Propmpt") 
{
    f.LogKeyEvent(keyCode);
}
```

Comment: `e.KeyCode` bitmask error cannot extract keys from key value\

Comment: ` f.LogKeyEvent(keyCode);`  keycode is in function where should i declare it in another class it returns error

Comment: You can just call it like that: f.LogKeyEvent(Key.L);

Comment: not satisfied actually i hace to call `LogKeyEvent(keycode)` from another class so where should i bring keycode as paramater

Comment: Keys.L working but i want to detect key press events and add in list box may be win active or nt

Comment: Then what you want is something completely different then your question. You want a global keyhook and not call an event from your class. I smell like you miss the basics of programming but you want to make a keylogger. I know how to do that but I won't post this as you clearly have not the knowledge to understand what I would post and you could also abuse it as malware